# Open ssl decryption gives 'Extra Arguments given' when trying to run a build pipeline for sfdx using circle ci

Tags: salesforcedx, circleci

i have this issue with openssl when i try to run a pipeline in circle ci.
Decrypting the  encrypted server key in my sfdx project fails.

this is the command i use to decrypt

```
 - run:
      name: Decrypt server key
      command:
        openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -base64 -K $DECRYPT_KEY -iv $DECRYPT_IV
```

but i get this error

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
 openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -base64 -K 
 $DECRYPT_KEY -iv $DECRYPT_IV
 Extra arguments given. 
 enc: Use -help for summary.

Exited with code exit status 1 
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

Comment: Does your `$DECRYPT_KEY` or `$DECRYPT_IV` environment variables contain spaces or special characters? Most likely you'll want to quote them

Comment: when you say quote them how do you mean ?

Comment: @DavidReed i understand what you mean now. And it seems you were right. Now i get an hex string is too long , hex value is invalid. I suspect that this has to do with the passphrase i might have used in encrypting the key file initially right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem appears to be that you haven't quoted your environment variables and they contain whitespace or special characters:

```
openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -base64 \
-K '$DECRYPT_KEY' -iv '$DECRYPT_IV'
```

After fixing this, you've mentioned that you're receiving an error

> hex string is too long , hex value is invalid.

It's not immediately obvious to me why this is the case since I cannot see (and you should on no account show me!) your keyfile and encryption passphrase. I would suggest beginning by reviewing all of your secrets for correctness and ensuring that you can decrypt the keyfile locally.

Then, I'd go through the [Salesforce DX Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ci_circle.htm)'s section on Continuous Integration using CircleCI, which it looks like you're probably following but might have missed a step on.

If you're observing different results locally and on CircleCI, validate that you have the same versions of OpenSSL installed - at least once in the past a version difference has also come with a difference in the default hash algorithm, which can result in divergent results. You may want to try redoing your setup and explicitly specifying a hash algorithm, such as `-md sha512`, to ensure you're using the same one everywhere.